# What does it mean when Lettuce Core logs indicate missing epoll and kqueue libraries during initialization?

Tags: java, redis, sdk, lettuce

I am using the Lettuce Core library, a Java Redis SDK, and noticed the following logs during the client initialization:

```
Dec 05, 2023 3:48:47 PM io.lettuce.core.EpollProvider <clinit>
INFO: Starting without optional epoll library
Dec 05, 2023 3:48:47 PM io.lettuce.core.KqueueProvider <clinit>
INFO: Starting without optional kqueue library
```

What's the significance of these logs, and should I be concerned about not having the optional `epoll` and `kqueue` libraries? I'm particularly interested in understanding any performance considerations or functional differences when these optional libraries are not included.